# link event.preventDefault doesn't work in a popup overlay window

Tags: preventdefault

I'm trying to prevent users to open directly unsafe links (http://).
here below is the code I'm using:

```
const container = document.querySelector('#container-id');
let links = container.queryselectorAll('a');
for (var link of links) {
  link.addEventListener('mousedown', self.blockUnsafeLink, false);
}
```

where:

```
// the function called in the event listener
this.blockUnsafeLink = function (){
let href = this.href;
if ( href.match(/^(http:\/\/)+/gi) ) {
     console.log(event);
     event.preventDefault();
     // do something here
}
```

This code works perfectly inside the website normal pages, the problem get out when I do the same thing inside a overlay popup window, at the point the the:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

doesn't work, the link gets opened.
I thought it was a problem of propagation, but reading the event in the console eveything seem ok.

```
bubbles: true
cancelBubble: false
cancelable: true
defaultPrevented: true
path: Array(12)
   0: a.highlight
   1: div
   2: div.scan-div
   3: div#text-mod-content
   .....
srcElement: a.highlight
target: a.highlight
```

If it can help, I also noticed that that if I go to debug the code in the Source section setting a check point on the event.preventDefault(), the event actually gets prevented (even in the popup window), the following steps do not open the link...

Does anyone has any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

I’d start by looking at the following:

1. in the `for` loop, the second argument to `link.addEventListener` is `self.blockUnsafeLink` but I don’t see where `self` is defined
2. in the function for the `this.blockUnsafeLink` event listener, you refer to `event.preventDefault()`, but there’s no `event` in the function parameters: perhaps the `event` that you’re using is coming from someplace else

Comment: sorry the self it's something I use in the object i write so the I can bring the object this inside the functions without confusing it the function this.. at the beginning of the object i declare a variable var slef = this;

Comment: I actually just solved the problem by changing the mousdown event with the click event, I honestly though that the mousedown fired before the click.

Comment: How curious. If you clicked on a link but did not release, I would expect the mousedown event (when it works) to fire, but not the click event. Along with the mysterious provenance of `event` in your listener I am perplexed but in any case congratulations on solving your problem.

Comment: Thanks, you see i did tried both the mousedown and mouseup events, that's why i never thought the click would work, but at the end I'm happy to close this chapter and go on with my work...